# In tendai, can the 1st and 5th teachings be called "potentiality" and "possible"?

Tags: western-philosophy, tendai

In tendai, can the 1st (huayen) and 5th (lotus) teachings be called "potentiality" and "possible", respectively?

I know the word "potential" from Heidegger's *Being and Time*, who has appeared in comparative studies. The most eye catching phrase, being "my ownmost potentiality for being", that amounting to death therein. By possibility, I just mean the not "necessary" or "actual", in the standard analytic philosophical terms.

I won't go into why I might suppose that could be a viable interpretation.

Comment: Are you referring to the classification into the five periods of the life of the Buddha by Hsuan Hua?

Comment: @Codosaur no i don't mean to limit it to Hsuan Hua, a name i do not recognise

Comment: What I meant was, by which classification are you referring to the 1st and 5th? There are [multiple classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiantai#Classification_of_teachings) of teachings in the Tendai school and I'm not sure which one you are referring to.